# Show only assigned custom taxonomies in a wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I've created with custom post UI a couple tag like taxonomies and I'd like to show only the assigned ones in the posts, not all of them.
I searched for a plugin that did the job but found none.
I've also tried to see if there was a custom code to put in the functions.php of the child theme but with no luck...

You can see what I mean [here](https://lawtelier.2fdesign.it/news/events/the-new-collective-trademarks-certification-trademarks/)

On the right side there are the two tag clouds showing the custom taxonomy I created, but I only want to see the ones assigned to the post.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried using `wp_get_post_terms()`? Seems like that's [where I'd start](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/).

Comment: Hi disinfor, thanks for your comment.
Unfortunately I'm not skilled at php, thus I didn't tried the wp_get_post_term().
Also the link you sent me is hard to understand. I get that with that string I can extract the custom taxonomy, but I don't know how then to show just the ones assigned. Also, since I'm using WPBakery to insert a widget in page right now it would be great to have i like a widget or a shortcode... but again... no clue on how to do so.

Comment: I think what you mean to be asking is how can you show the *terms* from a *taxonomy* assigned to the post. Right now, you are saying the tag cloud is showing all the terms from the taxonomy. You only want to see the terms that are assigned to that post. Is that correct? If so, what is your taxonomy named?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry I could't explain it correctly at first. I have 2 custom taxonomies for now, but probabily will be 3 or more in the future. You can see both of theme here: [link] (https://lawtelier.2fdesign.it/news/events/paycheck-protection-program-foreign-owned-us-based-businesses/)
You can find the two tag clouds on the right sidebar, they are called "Professionals" and "Practices".